# When i try to connect xbee s1 to computer using xbee regulated explorer, xctu is not seeing it

Tags: arduino, computers, xbee, software

So I have an Xbee regulated explorer with an Xbee and I am connecting

> DIN - RX
>
> DOUT - TX
>
> GND - GND
>
> 5V - 5V

but X-CTU(old version) is not seeing the Xbee when I click test/query. It goes and then says "Action Required unable to communicate with modem." I have the right com port and I tried connecting RESET - GND on my arduino and I tryed removing the chip entirely but nothing works. Please Help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're working with a Sparkfun product. I would suggest posting this on the sparkfun forum for a faster response: https://forum.sparkfun.com/